# How to add or change ssh keys default location?

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I am on OSX and trying to connect to ec2 instance on aws. Running key file name with entire path works, otherwise it gives error "file not found".

```
 ssh -i "my_key.pem" ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

> Warning: Identity file my_key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.

```
ssh -i "~/.ssh/my_key.pem" ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

Edit:

Better description: as long as the key is inside ~/.ssh/ directory, ssh should be able to find it just by the filename instead of giving the entire path. I am trying to add "~/.ssh/" directory to ssh path where it looks for keys. Not for a specific host or key.

> ssh with entire path works.

I have been able to run 'ssh -i "my_key.pem" ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XX' without giving entire path for the key in the past.
I have explored adding path in ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: Have you tried copying a file to the directory from where you want to do SSH ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Kri It is not off-topic, and has nothing to do with Super User.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Copying file to the directory or giving entire path for the ssh key would work as I shared in the examples above. I am exploring so that we can do ssh without the full address. I know for sure that this works if ssh is looking for the key in default location.

Comment: @KrishnaAswani Did you try the config approach I illustrate in my answer below?

Comment: I fail to see how this is *on*-topic here. There's no programming involved; it's just an `ssh` usage question.

Comment: @chepner I can see tons of ssh question on stack overflow. I think that's why the ssh tag exists too.

Comment: Most of them are probably off-topic as well. Just because a tag exists doesn't mean it *should* exist or that it is always used properly.

Comment: @KrishnaAswani Don't worry. It should exist. I have been answering such questions for the past 10+ years.

Answer (score 0):

> I have explored adding path in `~/.ssh/config` file.

That should be the solution, but in that case, the SSH URL becomes:

```
ssh <HostEntry>
```

With `~/.ssh/config` including:

```
Host <HostEntry>
   Hostname xxxx.xx.xx
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key.pem
```

---

> What I am looking for is changing path to the directory where ssh by default looks for key so that the entire path doesn't needs to be passed just the key name like `-i my_key.pem`.
> And then ssh automatically looks for it in the `~/.ssh/` directory

Simple:

```
HOME=/my/folder1 ssh ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XX
# or
HOME=/my/folder2 ssh ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

ssh will look for `/my/folder1/.ssh/id_rsa` or `/my/folder2/.ssh/id_rsa` depending on the `HOME` path value, set only for that one `ssh` command.

Comment: In this case it would for a specific host and with a specific key. What I am looking for is  changing path to the directory where ssh by default looks for key so that the entire path doesn't needs to be passed just the key name like `-i my_key.pem` . And then ssh automatically looks for it in the ~/.ssh/ directory.

Comment: @KrishnaAswani Sure, no problem: I have edited my answer to address your use case.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. This looks closer to my answer. Is their a way to specify it in config so that it applies to all the ssh and is not passed every time someone is running a ssh command. I have added description to my question to elaborate it further.

Comment: @KrishnaAswani Not that I know of: I would manage that through an ssh script wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! I will wait to see if someone else has a exact answer.